# What is the meaning of $ \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'd like to know more about the meaning of the set: $$ \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} $$I understand that it is the set of all equivalence classes of $$ [r]_m, r \leq m, \in \mathbb{Z} $$ What I don't understand is the name. Why divide a set by a multiple of the same set. I'd like to believe that it has some meaning and is not a pure notation convention.

Thanks

Comment: Good first question! You might want to learn about how you can quotient a *ring* by an *ideal*, but it's probably too advanced for learners at your stage.

Comment: it's the quotient of a ring by one of its ideals, the ring is $\mathbb Z$ and the ideal is $m\mathbb Z$ ( the subset of $\mathbb Z$ consisting of multiples of $m$).

Comment: In practice, it is the set of congruence classes for the relation $\: a\equiv b \mod m\iff a \text{ and } b  \text{ have the same remainder  in division by } m$.

Comment: "Why divide"? Because it is indeed a quotient. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) for *quotient ring* $R/I$. Here $R=\Bbb Z$.